# How to run function only if specific file runs?

Tags: python

I have multiple file1,file2,file3 we can fetch file name as environment variable as **env_file** :

If env variable is file2 then only run add function

env_file = "ref/file1"

env_file = "ref/file2"

env_file = "ref/file3"

main.py

```
def sub():
    do something
    
def add():
    run this function if file2 runs
    
def mul():
    do something
```

Expected output as:

> All function should run but **fun add()** should only when file 2 will run apart it should run all other function every time.

Comment: what do you mean if file2 runs? You are triggering it right? Do you mean if env variable is file2 then only run add function?

Comment: yes @albin-paul

Comment: Yes  if env variable is file2 then only run add function @albin-paul

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the environment variable from the os module.

```
import os
file = os.environ["env_file "]
```

You just need to check if file is  "ref/file2" inside the add function.

Comment: You mean like 
`import os

file = os.environ["env_file "]

def add():
    if file_name.split('/')[-1] in ['ref/1.1']
        print("Run File")
    else :
        continue`  @albin-paul

Comment: @ansh1 no need for the `else continue`. But,mostly yes.